# Quotient space of infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

On an exam today I used that if $X=\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ and $Y=\{f\in X : f(a)=f(b)\}$, then the projection $\pi: X\rightarrow X/Y$ has the property $\ker(\pi)=Y$. This led me to the following:

Suppose $(V, ||\cdot ||)$ is an infinite dimensional normed space and $W$ is a subspace of $V$ with $\pi:V\rightarrow V/W$ the canonical projection. Is there a canonical choice of norm on the space $V/W$ (say where $||\pi||=1$)? If there is such a norm, does $\ker(\pi)=W$?

My speculation is, ignoring some details of the quotient structure, if there is an accumulation point, call it $p$, of a sequence in $Y$ with $p\not\in Y$, then in the quotient space this would provide a sequence identically $0$, so $\pi(y)$ would necessarily be $0$.

I haven't really seen much about this type of problem before, thanks for the help.

Comment: Regarding the canonical projection $\pi:V \to V/W,$ we have $\ker \pi = W$  by definition.

Comment: @mattbiesecker Not necessarily. Say you have an open subspace $W$ such that $W$ is dense in $V$. Then $V/W=\{0\}$ but $V\setminus W\neq \emptyset$. In particular $W\subseteq \ker(\pi)$ but the reverse inclusion is not immediate.

Comment: @mattbiesecker Or, maybe you are right and this would be a cause of some failing of the quotient structure. Because not every subspace is closed but, $\ker(\pi)$ is for any bounded transform. Perhaps when $W$ is not closed $\pi$ is very discontinuous (and I should instead focus my attention on the metric for the quotient structure).

Comment: The Algebraic structure of $V/W$ is what it is.  i.e.  $x+W=W$ iff $x \in W.$     It'a late and I was confused myself for a bit.

Comment: Me too! Maybe I'll try to think of why this fails tomorrow. I'm guessing the norm I am imagining for the quotient is not well defined. You are right, the algebraic structure is not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case that $W$ is closed, there is indeed a canonical choice.
It is called the quotient norm and defined by
\begin{equation*}
 \| [\hat v] \|_{V / W}
 :=
 \inf_{v \in [\hat v]} \| v \|_V
 .
\end{equation*}
This also leads to $\|\pi\| = 1$ (in case $W \ne V$).

As already mentioned by matt biesecker, you always have $\operatorname{ker}(\pi) = W$, since this is independent of the norm.

This implies that if $W$ is not closed, you cannot define a norm such that $\pi$ is continuous.
This would imply $W = \operatorname{ker}(\pi)$ is closed.